# How is UWP main App singleton implemented?

Tags: c#, uwp

Answers to other questions about singleton implementation state that a constructor should be private for a singleton class. But UWP main `App` singleton class derived from `Windows.UI.Xaml.Application` has a public constructor. XML documentation generated by VS for it says:

```
/// <summary>
/// Initializes the singleton application object.  This is the first line of authored code
/// executed, and as such is the logical equivalent of main() or WinMain().
/// </summary>
```

When I try to create a second instance on mouse event I get

> Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))

So why is constructor public and how is singleton implemented to force only one instance of `App` to exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Singleton pattern**

The singleton design pattern restricts the instantiation of a class to one single instance. How that is achieved is not defined by the pattern itself, because the pattern is independent of programming languages. You can e.g. use a `.Instance` property or a `.GetInstance()` method - or even name it whatever you like, which may confuse people, but it will still be a singleton.

Using a private constructor seems to be good practice, because it is helpful as it will generate a compiler error when trying to use the private constructor. But: some programming languages don't even have a `private` keyword.

Obviously, UWP chose to restrict the number of instances in a way that causes an exception at runtime.

**Implementation**

Looking at the call stack, the catastrophic failure happens in

```
at Windows.UI.Xaml.Application..ctor()
at UWP.App..ctor() in ...\App.xaml.cs:line 29
at UWP.App.OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e) in ...\App.xaml.cs:line 43
```

So the App class constructor calls the base class constructor which throws an exception. Since `Windows.UI.Xaml.dll` is not a .NET DLL, I can't look into it with dotPeek or dnSpy.